# Drupal REST server, multipart/form-data image upload issue from iOS App using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, drupal, rest, asihttprequest

I am developing an iOS app that uploads an image and text to a Drupal REST server. The image and text are to be stored in a MySQL table.

I am using ASIHTTPRequest to to do a POST to my REST server.
On the server side, I followed this example for setting up a Drupal REST server: http://drupal.org/node/1246470

The issue I am having is I do not know how to to reference the image on the REST server. Whenever I try to send the information, I keep getting the error **"HTTP/1.0 406 Not Acceptable: Missing issue attribute image"**. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong or what I am missing?

My iOS version is 5.1.
My Drupal version is 7.8.

My iOS code is the following:

```
 NSString* timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

//Add the timestamp to the filename
NSMutableString* filename = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"issue-"];

[filename appendString: timestamp];
[filename appendString: @".png"];

//Convert the image into an NSData object
NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: SERVICE_URL];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL: url];

[request setPostValue: emailAddress forKey:@"email"];
[request setPostValue: details forKey:@"details"];
[request setData: imageData withFileName: filename andContentType: @"image/png" forKey: @"image"];

[request setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[request startSynchronous];
```

As for the server side, here is where I setup the hook_services_resources:

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_services_services().
*/
function issue_services_resources() {
  return array(
    'issue' => array(
      'retrieve' => array(
        'help' => 'Retrieves an issue',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'issue'),
        'callback' => '_issue_retrieve',
        'access callback' => '_issue_access',
        'access arguments' => array('view'),
        'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => 'The id of the issue to get',
            'source' => array('path' => '0'),
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'create' => array(
        'help' => 'Creates an issue',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'issue'),
        'callback' => '_issue_create',
        'access arguments' => array('issue service create'),
        'access arguments append' => FALSE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'data',
            'type' => 'struct',
            'description' => 'The issue object',
            'source' => 'data',
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'update' => array(
        'help' => 'Updates an issue',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'issue'),
        'callback' => '_issue_update',
        'access callback' => '_issue_access',
        'access arguments' => array('update'),
        'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => 'The id of the node to update',
            'source' => array('path' => '0'),
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
          array(
            'name' => 'data',
            'type' => 'struct',
            'description' => 'The issue data object',
            'source' => 'data',
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'delete' => array(
        'help' => 'Deletes an issue',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'issue'),
        'callback' => '_issue_delete',
        'access callback' => '_issue_access',
        'access arguments' => array('delete'),
        'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'nid',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => 'The id of the issue to delete',
            'source' => array('path' => '0'),
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'index' => array(
        'help' => 'Retrieves a listing of issues',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'issue'),
        'callback' => '_issue_index',
        'access callback' => 'user_access',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'access arguments append' => FALSE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'page',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => '',
            'source' => array(
              'params' => 'page',
            ),
            'optional' => TRUE,
            'default value' => 0,
          ),
          array(
           'name' => 'parameters',
           'type' => 'array',
           'description' => '',
           'source' => 'param',
           'optional' => TRUE,
           'default value' => array(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I have a hunch it may be the arguments for the "create". From what I have, I only have the "data" or type "struct". It looks I may need to have an additional argument for the image? If so, what would it be?

and here is where I do the check and setting of the 406 error:

```
function _issue_create($data) {

if (isset($data) &&  is_array($data)) $data=(object) $data; 

  unset($data->id);
  $data->created = time();
  $data->modified = time();

  if (!isset($data->email)) {
    return services_error('Missing issue attribute email address', 406);
  }

  if (!isset($data->details)) {
    return services_error('Missing issue attribute details', 406);
  }

  if (!isset($data->image)) {
    return services_error('Missing issue attribute image', 406);
  }

  issue_write_issue($data);

  return (object)array(
    'id' => $data->id,
    'uri' => services_resource_uri(array('issue', $data->id)),
  );
}
```

The issue is where I do the check:

```
if (!isset($data->image))
```

It seems this is not the correct manner for checking whether the image data is present... What is the correct way to reference the image data?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally know what I have to do. Silly me, I forgot that there was the php global called $_FILES which is the uploaded file! When I remembered that, it was very easy to store the image into the MySQL table.